# Laravel homestead Vagrant: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: mysql, vagrant, laravel-5, homestead

I set up Laravel HomeStead due do documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead

After commands

> vagrant up
>
> vagrant ssh

My sites works correctly and I can connect to mysql (MariaDB) with default username/password

> mysql -uroot -psecret

without problem. But unfortunately my happiness is not long because after 5 mins since moment of initialization vagrant (vagrant up) connection to mysql has been lost and I got error on attempt of connection to mysql from console

> vagrant@homestead:~$ mysql -uroot -psecret
>
> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't
> connect to local MySQL server through socket
> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

As a result file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock is disappeared though it has been there at once after initialization (vagrant up)

If say all shortly:
***Everything works nice for 5 mins then connection to mysql is lost (***

Could someone help me to resolve this issue ?

Thanks in advance,

Yevgenii

Comment: Maybe db Server was stopped?

Comment: It seems that server db is terminated after working for 5 mins.
And I can't start it.

vagrant@homestead:~$ /etc/init.d/mysql start

Job for mariadb.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!

vagrant@homestead:~$ systemctl status mariadb.service
Aug 17 08:31:49 homestead systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.

Comment: Apparmor was the culprit. Solution is here https://askubuntu.com/questions/750604/why-does-mariadb-keep-dying-how-do-i-stop-it